# My code/javascript sometimes works in Internet Explorer and sometimes doesn't. It works in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I've created a directory search feature and uses an ajax call to a file within the project folder. It works in Chrome and Firefox, but only sometimes works in Internet Explorer.

I have gotten it to work in Internet Explorer, but this requires me to copy and paste the code into a new folder and hope that it works. This is strange behavior because I'm not changing a single thing in the code and it will sometimes work.

If I get it to work on Internet Explorer and copy/paste the "working" files - it doesn't always work again.

Originally I was using some ES6 that isn't supported by IE, but I have fixed those issues. I think it might be something wrong with the .ajax call? But I can't figure out what.

**AJAX Call**

```
function getADInfo(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../js/roster.json",
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success from getADInfo');
            // employees.push(...data);
            Array.prototype.push.apply(employees, data);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
}
```

**This should search through the json file and display matches**

```
function findMatches(wordToMatch, employees) {
    return employees.filter(function(person) {
        var regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
        var nameString = person.Name.split(", ")[1] + " " + person.Name.split(", ")[0];
        var displayFirstName = person.DisplayName.split(", ")[1];
        return person.GivenName.match(regex) || person.Surname.match(regex) || nameString.match(regex) || displayFirstName.match(regex);
    });
}

function displayMatches() {
    $('.suggestions').show();
    var matchArray = findMatches(this.value, employees);

    // var html = matchArray.slice(0,10).map(person => {
    //     var regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
    //     var firstName = person.GivenName.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
    //     var lastName = person.Surname.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
    //     var extension;
    //     if (person.Phone_Ext1 !== null){
    //         extension = person.Phone_Ext1;
    //     } else {extension = "N/A"}

    //     return `
    //         <li class="search-item" data-id=${person.EmployeeID}>
    //             <span class="person">${firstName} ${lastName}</span>
    //             <span class="phone-ext">Ext. ${extension}</span>
    //         </li>
    //     `
    // }).join('');

    var html = [];

    for(var i=0; i < matchArray.slice(0,10).length; i++){
        var person = matchArray.slice(0,10)[i];
        var regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
        var hilight = '<span class="hl">' + this.value + '</span>';
        var firstName = person.GivenName.replace(regex, hilight);
        var lastName = person.Surname.replace(regex, hilight);
        var extension;
        var showdisplayname;


        if (person.DisplayName.split(", ")[1] !== person.GivenName){
            showdisplayname = "(" + person.DisplayName.split(", ")[1] + ")";
            showdisplayname = showdisplayname.replace(regex, hilight);
        } else {
            showdisplayname = "";
        }

        if (person.Phone_Ext1 !== null){
            extension = person.Phone_Ext1;
        } else {
            extension = "N/A"
        }

        var list =
            '<li class="search-item" data-id=' + person.EmployeeID +'>' +
            '<span class="person">' + firstName + ' ' + lastName + ' ' + showdisplayname + '</span>' +
            '<span class="phone-ext">Ext. ' + extension + '</span>' +
            '</li>';

        html.push(list);
    }
    html = html.join('');

    if ($('#search-box').val() == ""){
        suggestions.innerHTML = "";
    } else {
        suggestions.innerHTML = html;
    }
}
```

A dropdown should appear as I type, but nothing happens on Internet Explorer. It works fine on other browsers.
When I check the console, I'm getting a status 200, but it's an error

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKvhL.png)

Comment: `url: "../../js/roster.json",` is this url still correct after you moved the code to a new folder? any errors on console?

Comment: Can you clarify what behavior you're seeing? You say "Not working" but don't say what exactly isn't working. Is the data not showing up after your AJAX Call? The AJAX looks good to me.

Comment: @Huangism yes that is still correct. The console error just shows that the status is 200 but nothing being returned

Comment: @shadoe2020 I've updated with a screenshot

Comment: Do those elements have a Z-index set in the CSS?

Comment: It is better, If you post a screenshot of the error message and please try to inform us, Which version of IE you are using currently? Try make a test with any other machine to check the output. It may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: When is `displayMatches` being called?